# Error whois module not callable

Tags: python, whois

i try to use this code:

> https://bitbucket.org/richardpenman/pywhois/src/50b5966b55663b3a95e157680dc033b321360eac?at=default

```
import whois
w = whois.whois('webscraping.com')
```

but i get the error message:

```
wh = whois.whois('example.com')
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

anyone know how to solve this problem ?

Comment: Its a module, not a function. The error message is pretty clear about that.

Comment: how do you installed it?

Comment: i did with sudo apt-get install python-whois

Comment: i  just fixed this, i need to install with "pip install python-whois" thank you all for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apt-get install python-whois` install [this module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/whois). You should install `python-whois` with pip

Comment: yes, you are right. previous i not use pip. but this solved now

Comment: @herman, if problem solved, please accept the reply so that the question is closed.